# segfault error: struct, pointer, 2D array

Tags: c

I am playing around with pointers and structs. This is the program I have been messing with. I am getting a segfault error and I am not sure why. I have looked through it for awhile but can't seem to pinpoint the issue. Can someone explain it to me?

EDIT: in createArray I am getting a segfault at *purp[i][j] = '1';

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct purple_struct{
  int x;
  int y;
  char **purp;
};

void print(int x, int y){
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);

    return;
}

void createArray(char*** purp, int x, int y){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < y; ++j){
            *purp[i][j] = '1';
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main(){
    int i, j;

    struct purple_struct dog;

    dog.x = 3;
    dog.y = 4;

    dog.purp = (char **)malloc(dog.x * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < dog.x; ++i){
        dog.purp[i] = (char *)malloc(dog.y * sizeof(char));
    }

    createArray(&dog.purp, dog.x, dog.y);

    for (i = 0; i < dog.x; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < dog.y; ++j){
            printf("%c", dog.purp[i][j]);
        }
    }

    print(dog.x, dog.y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: perfect time to start with a debugger like `gdb`

Comment: Hint: don't tend to become a three-star programmer.

Comment: Not even that is necessary. On a normal debugger, like the Eclipse one, going line by line will show you where the error is.

Comment: 'printf' has also always been my friend

Comment: I am taking c in college. My professor is the worst and the textbook doesn't explain pointers very well. I don't know how to use a debugger since I am a beginning programmer and no one ever taught me.  I asked on here to get help from an actual person becuase even if a debugger pointed out the issue I doubt I would understand why it's an issue. but thanks I guess..

Comment: @Erica You need to know about debuggers if you are learning C. It's crucial. In which program are you writing C?

Comment: @JoãoPereira I used gdb. it gave me the seg fault at the line *purp[i][j] = '1'; but I don't know why.

Comment: What is `dog.x` and what returns `sizeof` ?...same for `dog.y` .

Comment: @Michi dog.x and dog.y is the int x and int y in my struct. I dont know what you mean by returning size of? its a built in function.

Comment: @Michi I am trying to store 1's in every spot in my 2D array that is stored in the struct.

Comment: `*purp[i][j] = '1';` --> `(*purp)[i][j] = '1';` or `void createArray(char** purp, int x, int y){` .. `purp[i][j] = '1';` call `createArray(dog.purp, dog.x, dog.y);`

Comment: @Erica your program needs some fix, but a direct cast shows you how it should work. [Click](http://ideone.com/IBS8I5)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh hope I am not ruining your hint but definitely Google their hint.

Comment: thank you. That helped me alot! It works now. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Erica Any way I meant something like [This](http://ideone.com/h9tgqh)

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted. It was a basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).  Just like in mathematics, where an expression like 1 + 2 × 3 means 1 + (2 × 3) and not (1 + 2) × 3, programming languages have rules as to the order in which different operators in an expression are performed.

The rules for C are here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

In your case, the problem is that *purp[i][j] actually means *(purp[i][j]), and not (*purp)[i][j] as you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
void createArray(char*** purp, int x, int y){
*purp[i][j] = '1';
```

I think they should be

```
void createArray(char** purp, int x, int y){
purp[i][j] = '1';
```

And in main

```
createArray(&dog.purp, dog.x, dog.y);
```

'&' is not needed here because you're already passing a pointer. '&' is usually used to pass the address of a variable.
Correcting these few things it compiles just fine, not sure about what you want to do.